# Earthing requirement according to power supply

Tags: design, compliance

I was wondering regarding the requirement of earthing that is it dependent on the Input value of power or not?

If a device is powered using 24V, 1.5A adaptor then is it mandatory to provide earthing in the product?

Kindly provide the range of inputs in which earthing is required.

Comment: The earthing requirement has more to do with the type of insulation of the power supply concerned rather than the power rating. For power bricks up to a 100 or so Watts they can be 'double insulated' meaning there is two insulation barriers. There's also local electrical rules that come into play. So the criteria is more like local rules, intended usage etc. If you are part of an educational institution, many of these have access to world standards. Maybe other respondents can give you guidance as to specific standards to read that will likely bore you to death!

Comment: Thanks kartman for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's *way* more complex than that.

Earthing requirements in fact depends on the local laws. In most parts of the world, if the equipment is not of a peculiar type (like medical) it is *not* required to provide an earth for such a kind of load *if* you ensure that double insulation is provided (and that's a can of worms for itself)

If you are unsure about your safety requirements the best course is simply to buy a ready to use pre-certified power supply.

Comment: Thank you lorenzo for the information.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on where your 24V comes from. SELV is isolated from the AC supply. PELV or FELV aren't, and probably need earthing unless your kit is all double insulated.

Comment: Thanks simon for the information.